# How can I execute php before posting to someone elses script from a form?

Tags: php, email, post

I have a contact form which posts to mailchimp - but in certain cases, I also want it to send out an email.

I considered changing the `<form action="...` from mailchimp to my own page, containing something similar to the following:

```
<form action="mailchimp_url..." ...>

<? foreach($_POST as $name=>$value){?> 
    <input type="hidden" name="<? echo $name;?>" value="<? echo $value;?>"> 
<? }?> 

<? //mail the stuff I want somewhere else ?>
```

I could then just auto execute this on pageload with javaScript.

The Problem is, IF this works, it will be dependant on JavaScript, or will require an additional button click for the user.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you can change the form to POST to your own page, then use `cURL` to execute a POST to the mailchimp URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post to your own server first

```
<form action="your_path" ...>
```

Then use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to post the same data to mailchimp

Here is a good example on [how to](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

Comment: You can also use AJAX to intercept the form submit and send whatever data to your own server before submitting to mailchimp. However, this won't work for the people without Javascript on (like bots).

Comment: Hey, so this actually didn't really do what I want it to. The curl method loads mailchimps page within my own, and seems to display it incorrectly to boot.  See my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184620/using-curl-to-post-form-to-two-places.

Answer (score 0):

this code will be done if you come from another form, submited.
Then your $_POST will be parse. But because $_POST exists only if a form is posted, you can't use it before.
What do you want to do exactly? If you want to add hidden input in your form fontion of specific params, you may use $_GET or maybe $_SESSION