# Using cURL to POST form to two places

Tags: php, forms, post, curl, mailchimp

Yesterday I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165649/how-can-i-execute-php-before-posting-to-someone-elses-script-from-a-form) about how I could go about hijacking my MailChimp contact form to send an additional email (when certain conditions are met).

I wrote changed the `action="...` from the MailChimp URL to my own `process_email.php` with code resembling the following:

```
extract($_POST);
$url = 'http://myMailchimpUser.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post';
$fields = array(
    'u' => urlencode($u),
    'id' => urlencode($id),
    'group' => http_build_query ($group),
    'MERGE1' => urlencode($MERGE1),
    'MERGE2' => urlencode($MERGE2),
    'MERGE3' => http_build_query($MERGE3),
    'other_more_info_text' => urlencode($other_more_info_text),
    'submit' => urlencode($submit)
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have yet to add the code which sends the email to myself, but that should be trivial.  The problem I'm having with *this* code is that instead of redirecting me to the MailChimp page, its actually loading within `process_email.php` (and its loading incorrectly to boot.)

I know I can accomplish what I want to do if I used JavaScript, but it seems to me that isn't the proper way to go about this.  Can anyone offer me any help?

Comment: cURL is not meant to redirect the user, but create a complete request from the server to the `$url`. Are you expecting the user to be redirected to `$url`?

Comment: yeah, I should probably just re-open, or ask the original question again. I really just want to know how to run my own PHP script (to send a quick mail) as (or before) POSTing my mailchimp form like normal. Previous question said cURL was the way to go, but its looking less like the case.

Comment: cURL is an option - but you have to use *their* api. Like I said yesterday, it would be easier to just have a Javascript event on form submit that alerted your server with the data *before* submitting to the actual mailchimp page. Lookup ajax form submit with jQuery.

Comment: In that case, if you want to post user info to another script, without changing the behaviour, you should add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`. Because by default CURL will take the output and print it.

Comment: @Xeoncross - thanks.  I'll go read up on cURL a little more. I may just cave and use js though.

Comment: @MathieuImbert - that didn't seem to do anything... but I'm checking out the documentation a bit more now to try to solve this bad-boy myself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly: you want to POST data locally first then let the form POST to Mailchimp. If that is what you are trying to do, then using some JS connected to the form (or a form button) is probably the best way to go. I think it *is* the proper way to go in your situation.

Something jQuery like below would work to POST the form locally first, and once that request is complete it would submit the form using the given action url (mailchimp).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-button').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("your_email_parser.php", $('#form-id').serialize(), function(){
            $('#form-id').submit();
        });
    });
});

...

<form id='form-id' action='http://myMailchimpUser.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post' method='post'>
    ...
    <input type='submit' id='submit-button' />
</form>
```

Comment: Ah excellent. Thank You. I ended up trying something similar (with a submit event handler) but it ended up being much more convoluted than your answer - and is still kind of buggy. I'm on another project at the moment, but I'll give you an check-mark once I try this out.

Comment: Hey, wondering if you can offer any insight into this - still not working properly :(  Its posting fine to my_email_parser, but for some reason its not submitting the form to mailchimp afterwards.

Comment: the line `$('#mailchimp_signup').submit();` seems like its executing and that is definitely the correct id on my form, but nothing happens.

Comment: Hard to tell; but one thing that's different in this example is that I used a click event (not submit event) to capture and post the data to your email parser in this line `$('#submit-button').click(function(event){`. If you use something like `$('#form-id').submit(function(event){event.preventDefault()});` your form will never be able to post normally because you stop all submit event. Try putting an `alert()` before `$('#form-id').submit();` to make sure you are getting there and maybe using a link or something other than `<input type='submit' id='submit-button' />` for the click event