# How can I post my form to a custom php script in addition to MailChimp

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, mailchimp

Can anyone offer me any help, or advice to debug this issue?

**I have a form which `POST`'s to MailChimp:**

```
<form id="mailchimp_signup" action="http://MY_MC_ACCT.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
...
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Subscribe to list">
...
```

**But I need this form to send out an additional email if certain conditions (a selected checkbox) are met:**

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    if( $('input[name="more_info"]:checked').val() && !$('#mailchimp_signup').hasClass('success') ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("../process_email_form.php", $('#mailchimp_signup').serialize(), function(){
            alert('posted');
            $('#mailchimp_signup').submit();
        });
    }            
});
```

**Whats Happening:**

- `process_email_form.php` is working fine, and sending out an email.
- the `alert('posted')` *is* triggering.
- Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the form to submit to MailChimp. The alert fires, but then nothing... I don't see any errors in the console.
- Typing `$('#mailchimp_signup').submit();` directly into the console does not even POST the form to MailChimp for some reason

**More Background**

This is actually the 3rd question I've written pertaining to this problem.  At first I tried to solve it with cURL, but that seemed to be the wrong approach.  For reference:

1. [How can I execute php before posting to someone elses script from a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165649/how-can-i-execute-php-before-posting-to-someone-elses-script-from-a-form)
2. [Using cURL to POST form to two places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184620/using-curl-to-post-form-to-two-places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just submit the form pragmatically after the first request is complete.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
        if( $('input[name="more_info"]:checked').val() && !$('#mailchimp_signup').hasClass('success') ){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("../process_email_form.php", $('#mailchimp_signup').serialize(), function(){
                alert('posted');
                $.post($('#mailchimp_signup').attr('action'),$('#mailchimp_signup').serialize(),function(html){
                    //do something with the result eg. $(document).html(html);
                });
            });
        }            
    });
```

Or you can run the first request without async, this will lock the browser until the ajax request is complete.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    if( $('input[name="more_info"]:checked').val() && !$('#mailchimp_signup').hasClass('success') ){
        $.ajax({
            url:"../process_email_form.php", 
            data:$('#mailchimp_signup').serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            async:false
        });
    }            
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
So, the first option looks like it would submit to MailChimp sort of behind the scenes? I need it to go to their success (or validation) page.

I tried out the second option and it seems to work - except for some reason the POST data is not going to the email_form like it did with my original code.  It now sends me a blank email.

Comment: You are correct. That being known, you have to use the second one. It will lock the browser up while the first request is being processed. I would show some sort of loading dialog while the first request is running.

Comment: With my broken code above, the process_email_form was filled out properly (just not posting to MC).  With your code (the 2nd one) it DOES go to both MC and my script, but my script doesn't see the POST data ( `print_r($_POST, TRUE);` returns `array()` ).

Comment: Try throwing a e.preventDefault in there and see if it still doesn't post the data. It **should** work, as far as I know. Maybe try setting a variable to the serialize(), `var data=$('#mailchimp_signup').serialize();` and then setting that in the $.ajax call. Also do a console.log on the serialize and make sure it is actually serializing the data.

Comment: My bad, I see the problem, change `method` to `type`. I am fixing it in the answer above.